# Make jquery script global

Tags: jquery, scripting

I have 5 diffrent scripts on page, which all do the same:

```
<script language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".hideshow-news").hide();
            $(".roll-li-news").click(function(){
                if ($(".hideshow-news").is(":hidden")) {
                    $(".hideshow-news").slideDown("slow");
                    $(".roll-li-news").removeClass('inactive');
                }
                else {
                    $(".hideshow-news").slideUp("slow");
                    $(".roll-li-news").addClass('inactive');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".hideshow-users").hide();
            $(".roll-li-users").click(function(){
                if ($(".hideshow-users").is(":hidden")) {
                    $(".hideshow-users").slideDown("slow");
                    $(".roll-li-users").removeClass('inactive');
                }
                else {
                    $(".hideshow-users").slideUp("slow");
                    $(".roll-li-users").addClass('inactive');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.hideshow-pages').hide();
            $('.roll-li-pages').click(function(){
                if ($(".hideshow-pages").is(":hidden")) {
                    $(".hideshow-pages").slideDown("slow");
                    $(".roll-li-pages").removeClass('inactive');
                }
                else {
                    $(".hideshow-pages").slideUp("slow");
                    $(".roll-li-pages").addClass('inactive');
                    }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Is there a way to make those 5 scripts global and join them in one script?
I made different classes as my menu have been opening on many spots.

Thanks for help.

Comment: -1 for not reading the docs of a library prior to using it. Sorry, you're a newbie, but you really could have done this.

Comment: @ Boldewyn, you are right. However, right now, the only thing I care about is that the thing actually works fine.
Thanks anyway for looking a dumb question.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick resolution to your problem follows. Delete all script tags and contents and just add this into your document preferably into the `<head></head>` section.

```
<script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

      var arr = {"news", "pages", "users"};
      var x;
      for (x in arr){
        $(".hideshow-"+x).hide();

        $(".roll-li-"+x).click(function(){
          if ($(".hideshow-"+x).is(":hidden")) {
            $(".hideshow-"+x).slideDown("slow");
            $(".roll-li-"+x).removeClass('inactive');
          }else {
            $(".hideshow-"+x).slideUp("slow");
            $(".roll-li-"+x).addClass('inactive');
          }
        });
      }
    });
</script>
```

This should do what you need, i didn't test it though. If you have other places that you use this with same structure, change the array like this:

```
var arr = {"news", "pages", "users", "members", "others"};
```

but as Boldewyn says you should go over basics more.

Hope it helps, Sinan.

Comment: Thanks!

Great solution, and yes like you said, I should sit down and take one good deep look at jQuery!

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, delete the last four script tags and use [this selector](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors) in the first one:

```
".hideshow-news, .hideshow-users, .hideshow-pages"
```

Comment: its not as simple as just changing the root selector, the click event will need a bit of reworking too, but this is basicly a good start yes

Comment: Replace .click() with .toggle()